# Discriminated union in React Props not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component which is supposed to generate a form. The types for the props are as follows:

```js
type GenerateFormProps<T extends z.AnyZodObject> = React.PropsWithChildren<
  | {
      questions: QuestionSet;
      schema: T;
      onError?: (errors: string[]) => void;
      onSubmit: (values: z.infer<T>) => void;
      disabledKeys?: string[];
      translationNamespaces?: Namespace
    } & (
      | {
          formType: "single";
          initialValues: Partial<z.infer<T>>;
        }
      | {
          formType: "multi";
          inferInitialValuesFromStep: Questions[];
          onNext?: (values: Partial<z.infer<T>>) => void;
        }
    )
>;
```

Within the component, I leverage Formik for error and input handling and have an `initialValues` and a `onSumbit` hook which are causing me a few TS issues...

```js
initialValues={Object.assign(
  formType === "single"
    ? (props.initialValues as Partial<z.infer<T>>) //! <- error here
    : parseInitialValues( //! and here
        (props.inferInitialValuesFromStep as Questions[])[step].questions
      ),
  formData
)}
onSubmit={async (payload) => {
  try {
    const partialPayload = schema.deepPartial().parse(payload);

    [...]

    if (formType === "multi") {
      setStep((prev) =>
        prev >= questions.steps.length - 1 ? prev : prev + 1
      );
      props.onNext.(partialPayload as Partial<T>); //! and here too
    }
  } catch (error) {
    onError && onError(getErrors(error));
  }
}}
```

In all these cases, the error is the same (for `initialValues`, `inferInitialValuesFromStep` and `onNext`): `Property 'x' does not exist on type {<large union for props>}`

I solved it for the `onNext` property by adding `'onNext' in props && props.onNext?.(...)`, but wanted to know if there was a better way of doing it.